# Comparator output getting meta-states

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, comparator

I have an LM311 comparator ([datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/172033/ONSEMI/LM311.html)) to produce an output of H (5V) and L (0V) from amplified noise.

The problem I'm encountering is that, because of the quick change of the noise's nature, sometimes the threshold of the comparator for state change is not truly met (but *almost* met), and instead of always getting an almost pure 5/0V at the output, I sometimes get meta states (like 2.5V, as you see in the image below). I will be reading this output in a microcontroller.

What would be the best practice to assure that this does not happen and I get the metastates? I'll be using a microcontroller (feed by the 5V from the voltage regulator); is it a good idea to leave it to the microcontroller?

Also, there are those "peaks" at the start of the signal after it is changed. I tried to attenuate them with a decoupling capacitor but didn't work. Any idea how I could smooth the signal?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbkHqU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: I think this is not a problem at all. The MCU will read these slow rising edges either as 0 or as 1. Since the signal is noise anyway, these MCU decisions are equally distributed. What impact would this have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you want to do, or nothing if it is fine as it is.

And there is no metastates, that's just a slow rising edge.

The problem is that all real world signals have a finite slew rate, and for the comparator output being an open-collector output, using a 10k resistor just makes the rise time slow, much slower than the fall time.

And as you see, sometimes the high time of the pulse is so short that the resistor can't pull up the voltage much before the signal falls low again.

There is no way to avoid it completely, as you can never have infinitely fast slew rate.

So the thing is, what you really want to do with the signal determines what do you want from the signal.

One option might be to do nothing. If you are sampling the signal with an MCU, the MCU can't read very fast signals anyway, so likely a halfway risen pulse with very short period does no harm.

One option is to make the pull-up resistor smaller in value, so it pulls the voltage up faster. The limit is how much current the comparator can sink while pulling the voltage low enough for the MCU to read it as low within good margin.

One option is to add a schmitt trigger buffer (or inverter) to the comparator output, so it will only change state when hysteresis threshold has been exceeded. The buffer will output a high slew rate push pull signal to MCU, and it may still have pulses so short that MCU can't do anything with them. Perhaps add some RC filtering before schmitt trigger to guarantee minimum time length between transitions.

One option is to add some hysteresis to the actual comparator circuit. The output voltage might still rise slowly, but it would stay longer high so after change the voltage stays stable.

One option is to read the level with MCU analog input.

Some MCUs have comparators built in.

You can also change to a comparator with push-pull output, but some pulses might still be very short.

Most microcontrollers have anyway some hysteresis and synchronizers on the inputs, so even if there is a halfway voltage on MCU input, it would still read as a definite 1 or 0 when you read the state.

Answer (score 1):

There are no meta states.

The rising edges of the output signal are so slow that in some cases, they do not reach the positive supply before the signal goes low again. (Falling edges are fast because they are actively pulled down by the comparator's output.)

To speed up the rising edges, use a stronger pull-up resistor (this will increase the power usage). Alternatively, use a comparator with push/pull output (e.g., TLV1805).

Comment: But if the microcontroller read the output exactly at 3.5V (you can see in the Picoscope image some states are in-between), it will read the 3.5V, not 5V or 0V. I do not want to discard the value.

Comment: @ludicrous Are you using digital or analog input on MCU? A digital input would have a defined levels which reads stably low or stably high. Analog input does not care.

Comment: And most microcontrollers have Schmitt-trigger inputs. The signal shown is digital enough for the µC.

Answer (score 1):

When the output has to go from 0 to 1, the resistor is charging the output. When output has to go from 1 to 0, the NPN is discharging the output. The resistor is weaker. So, if the pulse width is low, you can have the output not reaching 5V before the discharge happens (this is what you are calling meta states). Reducing the resistor value will improve this but, still you could see such issue when pulse width is even smaller.

You could consider adding a Schmitt trigger at the output before feeding it to micro-controller if you want to feed a clean 0-5V signal to the micro-controller.